# Consuming from queues based upon external event (event queues)

Tags: python, erlang, rabbitmq, celery, eventqueue

I am running into a use case where I would like to have control over how and when celery workers dequeue a task for processing from rabbitmq. Dequeuing will be synchronized with an external event that happens out of celery context, but my concern is whether celery gives me any flexibility to control dequeueing of tasks? I tried to investigate and below are a few possibilities:

- Make use of `basic.get` instead of `basic.consume`, where `basic.get` is triggered based upon external event. However, I see celery defaults to `basic.consume` (push) semantics. Can I override this behavior without modifying the core directly?
- Custom remote control the workers as and when the external event is triggered. However, from the docs it isn't very clear to me how remote control commands can help me to control dequeueing of the tasks.

I am very much inclined to continue using celery and possibly keep away from writing a custom queue processing solution on top of AMQP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With remote control commands you can [pause or resume](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues-adding-consumers) message consumption from a given queue.

```
celery.control.cancel_consumer('celery')
```

the command above instructs all workers to stop consuming (dequeuing) messages from the default celery queue

```
celery.control.add_consumer('celery')
```

remote commands accept ***destination*** argument which allows to send a request to specific workers

Comment: Thanks for the input. Remote control commands indeed look like a plausible option. However, looks like workers will still consume the tasks with `prefetch_count > 1` which kind of against defeats my purpose. Is there a way to enable these consumers with `prefetch_count=1`? Specifically I would like to have a) add consumer b) dequeue a single task from specified queue c) disable consumer for that queue until further external events

Comment: To configure a prefetch count for a worker use CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=1

Answer (score 0):

Two more exotic options to consider: (1) define a custom exchange type in the Rabbit layer.  This allows you to create routing rules that control which tasks are sent to which queues. (2) define a custom Celery mediator.  This allows you to controls which tasks move when from queues to worker pools.